# Inner Join in Entity Framework - how?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework-5

I am new to Entity Framework and I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT        
    WarningTypes.WarningTypeID, WarningTypes.WarningDescription, 
    WarningTypes.WarningArDescription, WarningReasons.ReasonName
FROM            
    WarningTypes 
INNER JOIN
    WarningReasons ON WarningTypes.WarningReasonID = WarningReasons.ID
```

and I need to convert this to be entity frame work so I Wrote this vb.net code:

```
Public Function selectAllWarningTypes() As System.Linq.IQueryable
            'Dim dt As New DataTable
            'wt.selectAllWarningTypes(dt)

            Dim query = _
                        From warningTypes In objSRSEntities.WarningTypes _
                        From warningReasons In objSRSEntities.WarningReasons _
                        .Where(Function(wr) wr.ID = warningTypes.WarningReasonID) _
                        Select warningTypes = warningTypes, warningReasons = warningReasons
            Return query


        End Function
```

The problem is: this run time error returned when I set result in gridview:

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported

Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of `DefaultIfEmpty` is to get the effect of a left join. If you do not want a left join, why are you using it?

Comment: yes your right I remove it and return inner join but now why this error returned when I set function selectAllWarningTypes() result in gridview

Comment: Check this [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)